# opencv binary threshold with C API: set threshold very small will filter out most pixel

Tags: opencv

Here is the picture in grayscale mode:

[image]

if I apply a Thresholding  and set threshold to 0. According to my understanding, the thesholded image will be mostly white. but the result is opposite.

Result is:

[image]

I also tried this:

build a image and set all pixel to 255. then apply the 0 threshold thresholding, the returned image is all 255.

**The question is:
in the picture is mostly zero (black) after apply thresholding.**

Here are the code:

```
IplImage*   g_image = NULL;
IplImage*   g_gray = NULL;
int         g_thresh = 100;
CvMemStorage*   g_storage = NULL;


void on_tracker(int){
    if(g_storage == NULL){
        g_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(g_image), 8, 1);
        g_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    }else{
        cvClearMemStorage(g_storage);
    }

    CvSeq* contours = 0;
    cvCvtColor(g_image, g_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvNamedWindow("Gray");
    cvShowImage("Gray", g_gray);
    cvThreshold(g_gray, g_gray, g_thresh, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvFindContours(g_gray, g_storage, &contours);
    cvShowImage("Contours", g_gray);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if( argc !=2 || !(g_image = cvLoadImage(argv[1]))){
        return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvCreateTrackbar(
        "Threshold",
        "Contours",
        &g_thresh,
        255,
        on_tracker
    );
    on_tracker(0);
    cvWaitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? This isn't a question. If you are just asking about why the threshold does this, then clarify that. Provide some code along with it.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I update the question.

Comment: Use `CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV` to invert the resulting mask.

Comment: and please DON'T use obsolete C api

Comment: @Miki, I don't see any obsolete mark when I check opencv C document. But I just rewrite this with python API. it work as I expected. most of image is white after thresholding with 0.

Comment: Yes, it's obsolete. Don't use it anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to @Miki's comments. this is caused by C API. I tried the same process with python API. the result is normal:
if I do thresholding with 0 threshold, most of pixel will be set to 255.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the different types of thresholding available to you in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html).

Starting with a 1D 'image' with a range of values (the black line) and threshold (the blue line):

[image]

...we can visualise the outcome of the different modes:

---

**Threshold Binary**

[image]

[image]

---

**Threshold Binary Inverted**

[image]

[image]

---

**Truncate**

[image]

[image]

---

**Threshold to Zero**

[image]

[image]

---

**Threshold to Zero Inverted**

[image]

[image]

---

Please update your question with your code so we know what mode you're using if this answer doesn't help already ;)

Comment: I have updated the code. I checked the doc before I post this question. My question is that the result I get don't match my understanding of thoery.

Answer (score 0):

The basic Thresholding is to check the pixels value (say from 0 to 255) to be above the Threshold value and to assign to the pixel a value of maximum value (high intensity: black)  this called Binary Thresholding.
In your case, when setting a value of 0 to the threshold, you actually filtering all your pixels since all of them (the low intensities and the higher intensities) have values above zero (0).

Maybe you would like to make a brighter picture - in this case use Inverted Binary Thresholding: in this case, you will get white picture when value is 0.

Comment: I think most of pixel should be greater then 0. so they should be set to 255. Then what I get should be a mostly white picture. But this is not the case.

Comment: As you mentioned, since most of the pixels are above zero, after threshold you will get all of them to be 255 - this means all of them will be black (high intensity).